# Why is JSON all uppercase

Tags: javascript, json, naming-conventions

I am aware that functions are conventionally expressed in camel case ie

```
function myFunctionName(){
    return false;
}
```

and constructors with the first letter capitalized ie

```
function Person(name){
  this.name = name;
}
```

But why is the JSON spelt in all capitals like in the function:

```
JSON.stringify(someValue);
```

I know it may be a bit of a pointless question but I can't seem to find the answer online.

Thanks

Comment: first of all JSON is not a function, it is an object. and JSON is an acronym.

Comment: Why isn't HTML all lowercase?

Comment: I understand that JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation but my question was why it was written in all uppercase. The way objects or variables are written often have a meaning as to why. An example off my head in C# would be how constants are written public const MY_CONSTANT = "constant value";@SalmanA

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because it is [an acronym for JavaScript Object Notation](http://json.org/).

In general, acronym conventions for JS seem less-defined / less-followed than other aspects. E.g., [LabKey guidelines](https://www.labkey.org/wiki/home/Documentation/page.view?name=naming) would classify this as a four-letter acronym requiring regular JS rules.